# .NET SOAP Service client certificate "Certificate algorithm is not supported"

Tags: .net, vb.net, soap, certificate

We are consuming a SOAP service via WCF, that needs a client certificate and a service certificate.
Testing it on develeper environment, using properly the certificates we are able to do a request. For this environment, we are using for client certificate one based with sha 256RSA as signature algorithm.

[image: SHA256 Cert]

When we try to consume the same service on production environment, we should use another certificate based on sha384ECDSA  as signature algorithm.

[image: SHA 384 Cert]

With this certificate, visual studio fires this exception  (Certificate algorithm is not supported):

[image: Error msg]

We don’t understand what are we doing wrong, anyone knows?
Why visual studio fires this exception?

Our project uses .net framework  4.8

This is the code that we use.

```
        Sub send()

            Dim clicert = New X509Certificate2("XXXXX",
                                                   "pass",
                                                   X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet Or X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet Or X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)

            Dim servcert = New X509Certificate2("XXXXX",
                                                    "pass",
                                                   X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet Or X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet Or X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)

            Dim binding = ProduccionGetCustomBinding()

            Dim client As New PortTypeClient(binding, New EndpointAddress(New Uri("urendpoint"),
                                                                                                     EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("dns"), New AddressHeaderCollection()))

            client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = clicert
            client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = servcert

client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None


            Dim obj As New ObjRequest

            Dim resp = client.send(obj)


        End Sub

Private Function ProduccionGetCustomBinding() As Binding


            Dim secBE As AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement(MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10)

            secBE.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Lax
            secBE.EnableUnsecuredResponse = True
            secBE.IncludeTimestamp = True
            secBE.AllowInsecureTransport = True
            secBE.SetKeyDerivation(False)
            secBE.AllowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply = True

            Dim textEncBE As TextMessageEncodingBindingElement = New TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
            textEncBE.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32
            textEncBE.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 524288000
            textEncBE.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 524288000
            textEncBE.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 524288000
            textEncBE.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 524288000

            Dim httpsBE As HttpsTransportBindingElement = New HttpsTransportBindingElement
            httpsBE.RequireClientCertificate = True

            Dim myBinding As CustomBinding = New CustomBinding()
            myBinding.Elements.Add(secBE)
            myBinding.Elements.Add(textEncBE)
            myBinding.Elements.Add(httpsBE)

            Return myBinding

        End Function
```

Comment: Does .NET 4.8 even support ECDSA? Is that cipher supported on the client machine you are using? Try the free IIS Crypto tool to check.

Comment: Yes it does. And, yes I enabled all schannel options and suites (including SHA384 hashe and suites that the SOAP service  owner tell us to activate)